# Edit control border and WM_CTLCOLOREDIT?

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface

I tried doing following, but the frame/border doesn't show up. I tried both FrameRect and Rectangle. 
Any ideas, why this is not working ?

```
case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT: 
          {
              HDC hdC = (HDC)wParam;

              SetTextColor( hdC, RGB(112,112,112) );

              SetBkMode( hdC, TRANSPARENT );

                RECT rect;
                GetClientRect( (HWND)lParam, &rect );                    
                HBRUSH hBrush = CreateSolidBrush( RGB(209,209,209) );
                   //FrameRect( hdC, &rect, hBrush );
                   Rectangle( hdC, (int)rect.left, (int)rect.top, (int)rect.right, (int)rect.bottom );
                DeleteObject( hBrush );

              LOGBRUSH lb;
              lb.lbStyle = BS_SOLID;
              lb.lbColor = RGB(249,249,249);
              lb.lbHatch = 0;
              return (LRESULT)CreateBrushIndirect(&lb);
          }
          break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it working.
The problem with the above code is when WM_CTLCOLOREDIT returns the system paints the edit control with the returned brush, so any painting done is wiped out. 
So instead of returning the brush created with CreateBrushIndirect, return NULL brush, by getting it from GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH).

The Rectangle function draws a rectangle. The rectangle is outlined by using the current pen and filled by using the current brush.
So that works.